# UIPageViewController not preloaded the very first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that works fine most of the times. the only problem I see is the very first time user goes to a page, say page 10, it doesn't preload the page 9 and page 11 automatically. but if user starts swiping, the preload works perfectly.

so the first time user swipes, the content is not preloaded and user needs to wait. is there "refersh" for uipageviewcontroller so i can force a preload when i initialize the uipageviewcontroller?

thanks!

-erben

Answer (score 3):

Try calling setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: three times in viewDidLoad (one for page 9, one for page 11, then one for page 10). Make sure the 3rd sets page 10, the one you want to appear.